# I want to set up my controller name same as like the input field data in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to make a controller in spring boot, the name of the controller has to be same like the user input.
If the user enters "name" in input field then my controller name is converted in to "/name".

```
 <div class="col-md-2">
    <input type="" class="form-control" id="controllerName" required>
    </div>
```

If user enter anything in this input field I want to make that text as my controller name.

```
@GetMapping("/inputFieldData")
public ModelAndView name(){
return new ModelAndView("Thanks");
}
```

Comment: you can use ```@RequestMapping(value="/{userInput}", method=RequestMethod.GET)``` . In this way , your user input will take you to this controller . Be aware that , anything entered inplace of 'userInput' will be redirected to this method

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by using **pathVariable**.

```
@GetMapping("/{inputFieldData}")
public ModelAndView name(@PathVariable String inputFieldData){
return new ModelAndView("Thanks");
}
```